# rsync: Exclude specific filetype in only one directory

Tags: bash, backup, rsync

I backup my data with rsync and would like to exclude a specific filetype in only one directory (and its subdirectories). For example I have:

```
$ ls Source/
Folder1/a.tar
Folder1/b.dat
Folder2/c.tar
Folder2/d.dat
Folder2/Subfolder3/e.tar
Folder2/Subfolder3/f.dat
Folder2/Subfolder3/g.pdf
```

Now I would like to sync all files except for the *.tar* files in *Folder2* and its subfolder. At the end it should look like this:

```
$ ls Target/
Folder1/a.tar
Folder1/b.dat
Folder2/d.dat
Folder2/Subfolder3/f.dat
Folder2/Subfolder3/g.pdf
```

Does someone know how to do that? I played around with the `--exclude` option, but without luck.

Comment: Play around with exclude some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**rsync** manual says

```
INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES
...
       o      use ’**’ to match anything, including slashes.
```

so you can do

```
rsync -a --exclude='Folder2/**.tar' Source/ Target
```

---

Note this is different from *bash*'s **globstar** option where you would use `Folder/**/*.tar`.